# Check Event(eventName(String), eventStartTime(LocalDate), eventEndTime(LocalDate)) slot empty or not

Tags: java

I have an Event Class:

```
public class Event {
  private String eventName; //getters & setters present
  private LocalTime eventStartTime; //getters & setters present
  private LocalTime eventEndTime; //getters & setters present
}
```

From database I am getting some list of events(every element of list having `eventName`, `eventStartTime`, `eventEndTime`).

I want to add new event which must not overlap `eventStartTime` & `eventEndTime` from the database list.

List of event having 2 elements.

```
Element 1: eventStartTime: 09:00
           eventEndTime: 09:30

Element 2: eventStartTime: 10:30
             eventEndTime: 11:30
```

**Example 1**: I want to add element3: `eventStartTime`: 09:20
                       `eventEndTime`: 09:45

My method should return false.
As `eventStartTime` (9:20) and `eventEndTime` (09:45) is overlapping with element 1(`eventStartTime` : 09:00, `eventEndTime`: 09:30)

**Example 2**: I want to add element3: `eventStartTime`: 09:45
                       `eventEndTime`: 10:15

My method should return true.
as there is no overlapping time exists

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yourself? If yes, can you post the code you have?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should write a method to check whether two ranges of `LocalTime` overlap:

```
static boolean overlap(LocalTime start1, LocalTime end1, LocalTime start2, LocalTime end2) {
    return (start1.isBefore(end2) || start1.equals(end2)) && (end1.isAfter(start2) || end1.equals(start2));
}
```

Then, you can use streams to run through your list to check if the given range overlaps with any of the ranges in the list:

```
boolean overlapsAnyEvent = eventList.stream().anyMatch(x -> overlap(
    x.getStartTime(),
    x.getEndTime(),
    eventToBeAdded.getStartTime(),
    eventToBeAdded.getEndTime()
));
```

And your method can return `!overlapAnyEvent` to indicate whether the event can be added.